# Docker Windows image with numpy

Tags: python, windows, numpy, docker

I've built a Docker image on Windows using an official Docker Python image.

I've added to the image some other Python libraries/packages such as pip,
coverage, mypy, pylint, and numpy. The Dockerfile seems to be correct.

When I spin a container of the image, I can access the installed packages/libraries *except* for numpy.

```
root@b4d044180979:/usr/python# pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
root@b4d044180979:/usr/python# which coverage
/usr/local/bin/coverage
root@b4d044180979:/usr/python# coverage --version
Coverage.py, version 4.5.1 with C extension
Documentation at https://coverage.readthedocs.io
root@b4d044180979:/usr/python# which numpy
root@b4d044180979:/usr/python# numpy --version
bash: numpy: command not found
root@b4d044180979:/usr/python#
```

Any idea why this is happening? 
  Why the numpy library is not recognized even-though the image building report indicates that it was successfully  installed?

```
...
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/92/c01d3a6c58ceab0e6ec36ad3af41bc076014cc916afcb979ab4c9558f347/numpy-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.8
MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.0
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update            && \
    apt-get -y install vim        

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip --version             && \
    pip install autopep8      && \
    pip install coverage      && \
    pip install mypy          && \
    pip install pylint        && \
    pip install numpy         && \
    pip list

CMD bash
```

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile ? I don't know numpy. is it supposed to be also an executable ??
I've just installed numpy in my virtualenv and there's no executable called `numpy`

Comment: I've edited the post by adding the Dockerfile. Thank you.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment I can't find an executable called `numpy`; but if I run `python -c "import numpy"` it works

Comment: I don't see any entrypoints defined in numpy's setup.py, so why do you expect it to have a runnable shell command?

Comment: Got it. Thank you.